# App getting crash on inserting dummy data using SQLite in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I was trying to use SQLite in my Android project and my app is getting crashed on inserting dummy data.

```
public void insertVehicle(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(PetContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_OWNER_NAME,"Tiki");
    values.put(PetContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_REGISTRATION_NUMBER,"DL154K5555");
    values.put(PetContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_TYPE,"Car");

    long newRowId = db.insert(PetContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,values);

    Log.v("CatalogActivity ","new Row id: "+newRowId);
}

public void onSubmitEntry(View view) {
    getvalues();
    getNotification();
   // Toast.makeText(this, "Submit button clicked_selected_CAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

insertVehicle();



    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Check_In_Page.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(uniqueId, notification.build());
}
```

FeedEntry class is

```
public static class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns{

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Vehicle entry";
    public static final String COLUMN_REGISTRATION_NUMBER = "Registration number";
    public static final String COLUMN_OWNER_NAME = "Owner name";
    public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "Vehicle type";

    public static final int TYPE_UNKNOWN = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_MOTORBIKE = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_CAR = 2;

}
```

stacktrace

```
04-09 19:36:31.018 16884-16884/com.example.android.parking12 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
04-09 19:36:31.023 16884-16884/com.example.android.parking12 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.android.parking12, PID: 16884
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3848)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3843)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463) 
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "entry": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Vehicle entry (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Registration number TEXT, Owner name TEXT, Vehicle type TEXT )
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1697)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1628)
       at com.example.android.parking12.Date.FeedReaderDbHelper.onCreate(FeedReaderDbHelper.java:29)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
       at com.example.android.parking12.Check_In_Page.insertVehicle(Check_In_Page.java:67)
       at com.example.android.parking12.Check_In_Page.onSubmitEntry(Check_In_Page.java:84)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3843) 
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463) 
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you create the table? Post your stack trace, please.

Comment: You should always post your stack trace

Comment: try changing the version of database. Most of the newbies makes mistakes on it.

Comment: yes I have created the table.public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE "+ FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME+" ("+
                FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                FeedEntry.COLUMN_REGISTRATION_NUMBER + " TEXT, "+
                FeedEntry.COLUMN_OWNER_NAME + " TEXT, "+
                FeedEntry.COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT ) ";
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);

    }

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your table and column names (the string literals) have spaces in them. Are you creating the table using single quotes in the actual query (escaping them using backslash)?

**Edit:** (after stacktrace was posted)

I was able to recreate your error by splicing in your code into a simple application. The error definitely comes from the space in the table/column names.

Based on this line from the stack trace:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "entry": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Vehicle entry (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Registration number TEXT, Owner name TEXT, Vehicle type TEXT )
```

**2 solutions:**

1. Either your table/column names need to be all one word literals:

   ```
   public static final String TABLE_NAME = "vehicleEntry";
   public static final String COLUMN_REGISTRATION_NUMBER = "registrationNumber";
   public static final String COLUMN_OWNER_NAME = "ownerName";
   public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "vehicleType";
   ```
2. Or you'll need to add single quotes to all the string literals of table/column names:

   ```
   public static final String TABLE_NAME = "'Vehicle entry'";
   public static final String COLUMN_REGISTRATION_NUMBER = "'Registration number'";
   public static final String COLUMN_OWNER_NAME = "'Owner name'";
   public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "'Vehicle type'";
   ```